# AdMob In House Ad eCPM Order

Tags: admob, ads

I'm a little confused on the matter of displaying my own in house ad's along side AdMob's ads with the use of setting eCPM values for order of importance.

I currently am just running one house ad along with AdMobs's network.

From the FAQ and AdMob help section I've come to the understanding that this is how the allocation will work.

For Example, I set AdMob's eCPM to $5.00 and my in house ad to $0.01, in this case an AdMob ad will only be shown if it's value is equal to or exceeds $5.00. If it doesn't, then my in house ad will be shown.

The issue I'm running into with that particular setup is that no in house ads are being allocated. I find it hard to believe that every ad that AdMob is able to allocate has an eCPM of $5.00. After a few days not one in house ad was allocated.

I thought I may have done something wrong in another area of my setup so I swapped the eCPM values, so AdMob now equals $0.01 and my in house ad now equals $5.00. I started to receive in house ads following the change in setup but it is opposite of which I understood.

Is my understanding of this backwards?

Ideally, I'd like to show AdMob ads as long as their eCPM value is high enough, if the eCPM is not high enough, I'd like to fill the ad space with my in house ad.

I've done some reading on eCPM Floor Beta feature but I don't believe it applies in this situation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So after some extensive experimenting, I've solved my question.

The idea with the eCPM settings is that you enter the eCPM performance of each network, and the mediation ordering is that the highest eCPM network goes first, followed by the second highest, and so forth. So the network I set at $5.00 got the first look.

To get the results I was seeking I needed to check the "Optimize AdMob Network" box in my mediation settings, and set my house ad's value to something reasonable, I set it to $1.00. Then at ad request time, AdMob will run an auction and automatically place itself in the correct spot in the mediation order based on what value it can get in that request. If AdMob can beat my house ad's value, it'll serve. If not, the house ad will serve first.

Comment: So, this is redundant with "ecpm floor beta" (https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3418058?hl=en)? I find the Admob configuration panel extremely unclear.

Comment: Yeah that is why I was so confused also. I believe the floor beta is best utilized when using multiple ad sources. At least that's what it seems like to me. I just use the implementation in my answer to get the results I require. Hope this helped you. @Gilbou

Comment: What i do not understand is that google is clear about that (here: https://support.google.com/admob/v2/faq/3406356?hl=en#3401093). I followed their instructions... it does not work (my in-house ads are not shown). On this page they wrote : "What this accomplishes is that AdMob network will first serve only ads that pay at least the eCPM floor value. Over time, this set up will maintain or increase AdMob network's eCPM value while the fill rate is likely to decrease, allowing the next ad source in mediation (in this case, house ad campaigns) to serve ads."

Comment: What do you mean with "something reasonable"? When you put $5.00 it did not work? thks in advance for your reply :-)

Comment: Originally when I set it to $5.00 I did not check the "Optimize AdMob Network" box so it was not working. If you check this box and leave your house ad's eCPM at $5.00 you're basically guaranteeing that only your house ad's will show as an AdMob ad with that high of an eCPM is rare. By setting it to $1.00 AdMob will try to beat that and if it does it shows it's ad. If it can't get an ad with an eCPM higher than a dollar, then my house ad shows. As far as a reasonable eCPM amount to set your in house ad at, that will take some fiddling around. @Gilbou