# Admob Custom Events in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, admob, custom-events

I have read the various documents and blogs on admob and custom events, but its not clear. Also as the website's UI is changed, the documents are a bit confusing. What to call and where?
I implemented admob custom events gave the 'AdUnitID' in my app.
Also on website i have created mediation named 'CustomEvents' having class 'CustomAds' and label value as 'AdUnitId'. 
I am getting admob ads but my custom class is not called. I dont know if i am missing something. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you plan to use the custom events for? Have you read [this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3083407?hl=en) and follwed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/mediation#customevents)? Do you just want to implement [AdMob in house advertisements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24046860/2108547)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer as everything was correct. Only a small mistake, in android it requires class name with package but in iOS we can give the class name only bundleIdentifier is not needed.