# Does activating House ads decrease performance of Admob's own network?

Tags: admob

I have never used house ads before on AdMob thinking that it may affect my normal ads stats and indirectly causes drops in revenue when switching back to regular AdMob network ads.

Does anybody have insider information related to this situation? For example, would you run House ads only, for 1 month and then get back to usual AdMob network ads? After getting back to AdMob network ads, would the revenue drop?

***Update***

I have to run HouseAds alone as they will be custom/manual sales by me. So someone will pay me to show their ads. In that case I must only show House ads. After that campaign is over, I manually go back to FULL AdMob ads. But would that cause a drop?

Comment: Run your house ads along side AdMob's ads. Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016340/new-admob-in-house-ad-ecpm-order/24046860#24046860) on how to achieve this. This will show your house ads when AdMob's eCPM drops below a certain threshold, ie $1.00.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I up-voted your answer on that question. In my case, I have to run HouseAds alone as they will be custom/manual sales by me. So someone will pay me to show their ads. In that case I must only show House ads. After that campaign is over, I manually go back to FULL AdMob ads. But would that cause a drop..? That is the question :|

Comment: My apologies @frankish. You should edit your question to include those details. I don't believe it will have much of an affect on your income once your house ads finish running. Perhaps just the first day will be hindered when AdMob ads start to ramp up again. I have no concrete examples to provide but, I have been in a similar situation.