# Admob ad house campaign / Impressions goal spread out

Tags: admob, ads, impressions

I am planning on launching an ad house campaign on a set of apps. I am unsure about how the impressions goal I will set will be spread over, on a day scale.

I guess that if i set 1000 impressions on a 5 days campaign , there will be 1000/5=200 impressions per day. 
But what about within a day ? Are the 200 impressions "equally" spread over 24 hours ? Or will the 200 ads be displayed during the first minutes or hours of the day ?

Thanks so much for any tip on that!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question but one on admob's business model and should be discussed with them or by reading their website.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ You're right that it's not a programming question (and I agree with closing the question for this reason) but I wish there was a place we could talk about monetization and promotions of apps we're writing which is, whilst not specifically programming related, is still very relevant to programmers. Alas, that place is not SO.

Comment: @kha: Um, there's a lot of other StackExchange sites. Maybe WebmasterPro is for you?

Comment: From my experience your in house ads will be filled ASAP. I believe there is a scheduling option when creating your campaign/ad to only show them during certain times although. Another option you may want to look into is using in house eCPM ads. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24046860/2108547

Answer (score 0):

The even delivery is supposed to be based on day, not hour. My last round of testing showed admob tried front loading within a day.