# Creating custom advertisements on iOS

Tags: ios, admob, iad, ads

I have an app that was sold in high volume. I want to advertise a new app in my other app. Is there a simple way to bypass AdMob or iAd and put custom advertisements in my own application?

Answer (score 1):

AdMob offers [in house ads](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3210452?hl=en).

1. Go to **AdMob.com**
2. Click **Promote** in the tab bar
3. Click **+ Promote New App** in the top left
4. Click **New House Ad Campaign**

Then, just follow the setup. You can offer impression goal or eCPM-based ads for apps or websites. If you're interested in eCPM-based ads, I'd suggest reading [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24016340/2108547).